# Is there any sect in Hinduism that believe in eternal heaven?

Tags: sects

There are many sect in Hinduism, so is there a sect in Hinduism that believe in eternal heaven.

Comment: Depends; if you mean heaven as "swarga-lok" then no; but if you mean mean places like "Vishnu-lok", "Brahma-lok", "Vaikunta-dham" then probably yes

Comment: The Madhavacharyas have the concept of eternal damnation for some souls for *Andha-tamas* - *tamo-yogyas*, then souls forever to be staying in here *nitya-samasaris* & then the liberated *mukta-yogyas*.

Comment: Vaikuntha and Kailasa are eternal heavens themselves.

Answer (score 1):

Vaishnava concept of Vaikhunta/Visnuloka,Shaiva concept of Kailasa/Sivaloka and Shakta concept of Deviloka are some concepts of eternal heaven in Hinduism.

Comment: Please cite source for your answer.

Comment: Refer [linked comment](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/45435/does-the-gita-contradict-the-vedas-in-these-verses-and-if-yes-is-there-any-univ#comment144033_45449)

Comment: Please re-edit this answer with appropriate linked sources and citations to support your arguement.